Facet search query in Oracle Text using Timestamp field type
I've a problem using timestamp type in oracle facet query.
I created this table
CREATE TABLE test_user_ft (
  id VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR2(50),
  surname VARCHAR2(50),
  age number,
  date_birth timestamp
);

then I created the following datastore and section group for a Full Text Search and facet query
BEGIN
    ctx_ddl.drop_preference  ('test_user_ft_ds');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('test_user_ft_ds', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute    ('test_user_ft_ds', 'COLUMNS', 'id, name, surname, age');
    
    ctx_ddl.drop_section_group   ('test_user_ft_sg');
    ctx_ddl.create_section_group ('test_user_ft_sg', 'BASIC_SECTION_GROUP');
    
    ctx_ddl.add_sdata_section    ('test_user_ft_sg', 'date_birth ', 'date_birth ', 'TIMESTAMP');
END;

And finally the index
CREATE INDEX test_user_ft_index  ON test_user_ft (id) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('datastore test_user_ft_ds section group test_user_ft_sg sync(on commit)');

My question is: how can I use date_birth field value format in a Oracle Text query for a facet search using SDATA function?
In Oracle APEX App Builder user guide I found the following sentence:
"For DATE or TIMESTAMP values, use the YYYYMMDDHH24MISS canonical format"
but I use some query like these
SELECT * FROM TEST_USER_FT WHERE CONTAINS(ID,'SDATA(DATE_BIRTH > "20100131020000")')>0;

I obtain Oracle Error:
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-12246: SDATA operand not compatible with the sdata section DATE_BIRTH
29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"

What is the right format value to use?

Why are you using section groups?

As an aside, AGE should be derived using TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_birth)/12) and should not be stored in the table as if its my birthday tomorrow then an AGE entered today will be incorrect tomorrow. I'm also not sure why you are using TIMESTAMP for date_birth and not DATE as both data-types have date and time components and you don't appear to need fractional seconds which is all a TIMESTAMP would add.

Have you tried a timestamp literal: DATE_BIRTH > TIMESTAMP '2010-01-31 02:00:00' (possibly using '' instead of ' to escape the single quotes)? But I still don't think that you should be using a section group and DATE_BIRTH should just be one of the columns of the data store.
